# I want to bind a class of bootstrap 4 to the form field

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-reactive-forms, angular-bootstrap

I just wanted to bind the bootstrap4 class "is-invalid" when Angular form field is invalid and touched . 
For that I tryed with =

```
<input type="text" #name class="form-control" [class.is-invalid]="name.invalid && name.touched" name="Name" [(ngModel)]='users.username'  required>
```

Actually this form regarding updating the Address so I have Already bind the user name with  ngModel , this form is just like Amazon or flipkat where  you can edit your Address

But using , 
**[class.is-invalid]="name.invalid && name.touched"** in the above code dosen't work .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `#name="ngModel"`

```
<input type="text" #name="ngModel" class="form-control" name="Name" required>
<small [class.d-none]='name.valid || name.untouched'>This field is required</small>
```